# Django accessing admin page and adding a new url - BEGINNER

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I have created a DJango project in eclipse. Later i added a new application (`R-CLick Project folder ---> DJANGO ---> Create application (manage.py startapp)`)

I names it `Super`.

Then again i created another new application (using the same steps described above), and named it `Human`.

In my project now, i have 2 applications created (In eclipse it appears as 2 packages).

I have a file called `admin.py` inside the package `Super`.

The code is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from Super.models import People
from Human.models import NormalHuman

admin.site.register(People)
admin.site.register(NormalHuman)
```

I even registered the 2 new applications in the `Settings.py` file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Super',
    'Human',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

I also made changes to the `urls.py` file.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
from Human.models import NormalHuman
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^normal/', NormalHuman),
)
```

Problems i want to solve:

1.) After restarting the server, when i try to navigate to the url `127.0.0.1:9095/normal` i end up in a 404

2.) I need to add `NormalHuman` to the admin page, so i have access to its content.

Comment: `NormalHuman` is the name of your model, not of a view. URLs only map to views. To edit your humans and super heros, you need to go to `/admin`.

Comment: can you show the code for urls file of both app?

Comment: You should re-read the tutorial pages on the admin. Nowhere does it say you need to add a new URL when you add a model to the admin. On the contrary, it explains exactly that you just need to register it. Anyway, mapping a URL to a *model* makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have already registered admin url so you do not need to add

```
url(r'^normal/', NormalHuman),
```

to see content of  NormalHuman model.

just simply hit

```
127.0.0.1:9095/admin/human/normalhuman
```

to see content of NormalHuman model.

Comment: So what you say is that i need not edit the `urls.py` class. However, i still end up with a 404 error.

Comment: Yes, it says 404. any clue

Comment: do you have separate urls.py files into your both apps ?

Comment: No i just have only one.